# Aggregate Time Series

Tags: r

I have a time series class that plots each daily value (river discharge) over the date range from 2012-01-01 through 2014-02-03. I want to remove seasonal variation by applying the aggregate() function but cannot find the correct syntax for the frequency parameter.

A sample of the data (with 2 variables) was created with dput:

```
structure(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04", 
"2014-01-05", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-07", "2014-01-08", "2014-01-09", 
"2014-01-10", "2014-01-11", "2014-01-12", "2014-01-13", "2014-01-14", 
"2014-01-15", "2014-01-16", "2014-01-17", "2014-01-18", "2014-01-19", 
"2014-01-20", "2014-01-21", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-23", "2014-01-24", 
"2014-01-25", "2014-01-26", "2014-01-27", "2014-01-28", "2014-01-29", 
"2014-01-30", "2014-01-31", "2014-02-01", "2014-02-02", "2014-02-03", 
"2014-02-04", "2014-02-05", "2014-02-06", "2014-02-07", "2014-02-08", 
"2014-02-09", "2014-02-10", "2014-02-11", "2014-02-12", "2014-02-13", 
"2014-02-14", "2014-02-15", "2014-02-16", "2014-02-17", "2014-02-18", 
"2014-02-19", "2014-02-20", "2014-02-21", "2014-02-22", "2014-02-23", 
"2014-02-24", "2014-02-25", "2014-02-26", "2014-02-27", "2014-02-28", 
"2014-03-01", "2014-03-02", "119000", "125000", "129000", "125000", 
"122000", "155000", "157000", "152000", "156000", "156000", "106000", 
"147000", "123000", "123000", "128000", "150000", "135000", "135000", 
"134000", "144000", "154000", "152000", "139000", "147000", "135000", 
"120000", "119000", "124000", "132000", "152000", "138000", "140000", 
"137000", "133000", "126000", "102000", " 82900", "133000", "158000", 
"116000", "145000", "151000", "125000", "130000", "116000", "137000", 
"133000", "129000", "128000", "126000", "135000", "136000", "153000", 
"172000", "4.5", "4.6", "4.6", "4.5", "4.4", "4.3", "4.4", "4.4", 
"4.4", "4.4", "4.5", "4.5", "4.5", "4.5", "4.5", "4.4", "4.3", 
"4.3", "4.4", "4.4", "4.4", "4.5", "4.5", "4.4", "4.3", "4.3", 
"4.2", "4.1", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0", "3.8", "3.7", "3.5", 
"3.3", "3.0", "2.8", "2.6", "2.5", "2.5", "2.5", "2.5", "2.6", 
"2.7", "2.5", "2.4", "2.7", "2.9", "2.8", "2.9", "3.1", "3.2", 
"3.3", "3.4", "3.4", "3.5", "3.7", "4.0", "4.2", "4.1"), .Dim = c(61L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("date", "disch", "temp")), .Tsp = c(1, 
61, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

When I try to aggregate (on only the disch data for the entire time period) my choice of frequency (which is 365 for the ts object) produces a blank plot. The syntax I use is:

```
plot(aggregate(dalles.disch.ts, FUN=mean, freq=365)
```

Reading ?ts there are examples for monthly data but not daily. Since I have daily data for all of 2012 and 2013 plus the first two months of 2014, what FUN and freq should I speciry?

Answer (score 0):

Would stl(), Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series by Loess, work?  I've used it for daily data using frequency = 7 as an argument in ts().

Comment: If it works, please mark the question answered.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the aggregate() function in the zoo package to aggregate to monthly, quarterly, or annual data. Second, there are a hundred ways to de-trend data. I suggest doing a more thorough search, but you can use loess models, diff(), moving windows, and countless other signal processing methods. The decompose() and stl() functions are the simplest options among them, which both use loess, which stands for LOcal regrESSion.